# How to you read a csv in SnowPark

Tags: csv, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a bunch of `.csv` file and i was looking for the easiest way to load them into SnowPark? I am not sure which are the APIs required.
If someone can point me to the APIs or provide a code example that will be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can do this directly in one step as Snowpark doesn't have an API for that.
What you can do is:

Load the CSV files to a stage.

```
// Upload a file to a stage.
session.file.put("file:///tmp/file1.csv", "@myStage/prefix1")
```

Create a DataFrame by reading files from the stage.

```
val dfCatalog = session.read.csv("@myStage/prefix1")
```

See more information [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowpark/reference/scala/com/snowflake/snowpark/FileOperation.html) and [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowpark/reference/scala/com/snowflake/snowpark/DataFrame.html) and [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowpark/reference/scala/com/snowflake/snowpark/DataFrameReader.html)